# Insert data into two dependent tables from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgresql (11) I have a table `pre_data` which contains 3 fields: `id_b`, `data_a` and `data_b`.

I would like to execute `INSERT` statements from this table into two other, `a (id_a, data_a)` and `b (id_b, id_a, data_b)`, where `b.id_a` has a foreign key constraint referencing `a.id_a`. Both tables should be filled with data from `pre_data`. Therefore table `a` needs to be filled first, since otherwise there would be no key `id_a` available for table `b`.

It would be great if such a query were possible:

```sql
WITH first AS (
    INSERT INTO a (id_a, data_a)
    SELECT t.data_a FROM pre_data t
    RETURNING id_a, t.id_b, t.data_b
)
INSERT INTO b (id_a, id_b, data_b)
SELECT id_a, id_b, data_b FROM first
```

But I know it won't work because the `RETURNING` statement can only reference columns from the table being inserted (`a`).

If I execute two separate queries, I have no way to join back data inserted in `a` with the original `pre_data` (`data_a` and `data_b` are not unique fields).

I'm hoping there's a way to do this without temporary tables, since the actual tables are pretty large.

Comment: Your example is not convincing, because you are not inserting any columns from `a` into `b`.  You can do the second insert directly from `pre_data`.

Comment: You are right, I missed a column in the insert. I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem, I ended up solving this by pre-generating the `id_a` values from its sequence:

```sql
WITH first AS (
    SELECT
        nextval('seq_id_a') AS id_a,
        t.id_b, t.data_a, t.data_b
    FROM pre_data t
), insert_a AS (
    INSERT INTO a (id_a, data_a)
    SELECT id_a, data_a
    FROM first
    RETURNING id_a
)
INSERT INTO b (id_b, id_a, data_b)
SELECT id_b, id_a, data_b
FROM insert_a a INNER JOIN first t USING (id_a)
```